# Getting Error when i start TorToolKit Bot telegram on vps

Tags: python

(venv) root@ip-172-31-40-27:/home/ubuntu/TorToolkit-Telegram# ./start.sh
[2021-07-06 14:12:16 +0000] [332160] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2021-07-06 14:12:16 +0000] [332160] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:80 (332160)
[2021-07-06 14:12:16 +0000] [332160] [INFO] Using worker: aiohttp.GunicornWebWorker
[2021-07-06 14:12:16 +0000] [332165] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 332165
2021-07-06 14:12:16,405 INFO MainThread root Database created
2021-07-06 14:12:16,406 INFO MainThread root Database created
2021-07-06 14:12:16,506 INFO MainThread telethon.crypto.aes cryptg detected, it will be used for encryption
2021-07-06 14:12:18,860 INFO MainThread pyrogram.crypto.aes Using TgCrypto
2021-07-06 14:12:23,218 INFO MainThread root Telethon Client created.
Pyrogram v1.1.13, Copyright (C) 2017-2021 Dan https://github.com/delivrance
Licensed under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License v3 or later (LGPLv3+)

```
2021-07-06 14:12:28,510 INFO MainThread root Pryogram Client created.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/ubuntu/TorToolkit-Telegram/tortoolkit/__main__.py", line 55, in <module>
    ttkbot.loop.run_until_complete(start_server_async(get_val("SERVPORT")))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/ubuntu/TorToolkit-Telegram/tortoolkit/core/wserver.py", line 334, in start_server_async
    await web.TCPSite(runner,"0.0.0.0",port).start()
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_runner.py", line 121, in start
    self._server = await loop.create_server(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1463, in create_server
    raise OSError(err.errno, 'error while attempting '
OSError: [Errno 98] error while attempting to bind on address ('0.0.0.0', 80): address already in use
2021-07-06 14:12:29,359 ERROR MainThread asyncio Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7f62991bcbe0>
2021-07-06 14:12:29,359 ERROR MainThread asyncio Exception in default exception handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1733, in call_exception_handler
    self.default_exception_handler(context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1707, in default_exception_handler
    logger.error('\n'.join(log_lines), exc_info=exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1475, in error
    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1589, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1599, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1661, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 954, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1186, in emit
    self.stream = self._open()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1176, in _open
    return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
NameError: name 'open' is not defined
Exception ignored in: <function ClientSession.__del__ at 0x7f629fcb8430>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 337, in __del__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1740, in call_exception_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1475, in error
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1589, in _log
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1599, in handle
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1661, in callHandlers
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 954, in handle
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1186, in emit
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1176, in _open
NameError: name 'open' is not defined`enter code here`enter code here`
(venv) root@ip-172-31-40-27:/home/ubuntu/TorToolkit-Telegram#
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing any of the products but tortoolkit is trying to listen to port 80:

`File "/home/ubuntu/TorToolkit-Telegram/tortoolkit/core/wserver.py", line 334, in start_server_async     await web.TCPSite(runner,"0.0.0.0",port).start()`

but the port on the machine is already used:

`OSError: [Errno 98] error while attempting to bind on address ('0.0.0.0', 80): address already in use`

I would recommend to find how that "port" variable is controlled and use a less used port. For local development it's best practice to use 8080 to 9000